# Why when using wait( ) , notify( ) , notifyAll( ) in java the thread using this part of code must be the only thread that own it's monitor?

Tags: java, multithreading

The idea that when you remove the keyword synchronized when using wait( ) , notify( ) , notifyAll( ) it raises an error while running the program I know that  wait( ) , notify( ) , notifyAll( ) must be included inside a synchronized block to make that thread using them the only thread owning the monitor on that pice of code but my question is : Why when using wait( ) , notify( ) , notifyAll( ) in java the thread using this part of code must be the only thread that own it's monitor ?

when remving the keyword synchronized from the pice of code that contains wait( ) , notify( ) or notifyAll() this raises an error while I found no logical reason for that error

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: And specifically, an example of a specific, useful use case where you might want to call the methods without holding the lock?

Answer (score 3):

Requiring that the lock on the object is held resolves a race condition.

Imagine that synchronized is not needed:

- Thread A checks a flag and decides it needs to wait
- Thread B sets the flag
- Thread B calls notify
- Thread A actually calls wait

Now Thread A will wait forever.

With synchronized:

- Thread A takes the lock
- Thread B wants to set the flag, so tries to take the lock, but is blocked
- Thread A checks the flag
- Thread A calls wait (which releases the lock)
- Now thread B can set the flag and call notify
- Thread A wakes up and sees the flag is set.

Comment: And on top of that, it also guarantees that some other thread C won't _unset_ the flag before A gets woken up. That is, A will see the world as B left it when B said to A, "ok it's your turn." (That gets a bit more complicated with notifyAll, but you do still get the situation where each thread gets to atomically set state before the next thread gets its turn.)

Answer (score 1):

When using `synchronized`, you're in fact locking an object.

```java
final Object lock = new Object();
// ...
synchronized (lock) {
    // ...
}
```

Only one thread at a time can lock onto that object. Unless you call `wait()`. If so, another thread is allowed for entering that critical section, doing it's stuff with that object and either calling `wait()` or notifying the other object holder(s) allowing them to continue past their `wait()` call.

```java
void log(String message) {
    System.out.println("[" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "] " + message);
}

final int max = 10;
final Object valueLock = new Object();
volatile int value = 0;

Thread setupThread = new Thread(() -> {
    log("Started");
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        Thread valueThread = new Thread(() -> {
            log("Started");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(1000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            synchronized(valueLock) {
                log(value + " -> " + (++value));
                valueLock.notifyAll();
            }
            log("Finished");
        });
        valueThread.start();
    }
    log("Finished");
}, "setupThread");

setupThread.start();

log("Waiting for the value to reach " + max);
synchronized(valueLock) {
    while (true) {
        if (value < max) {
            valueLock.wait();
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
log("Finished");
```

Output:

```
[setupThread] Started
[Thread-0] Started
[Thread-1] Started
[Thread-2] Started
[Thread-3] Started
[Thread-4] Started
[Thread-5] Started
[Thread-6] Started
[Thread-7] Started
[Thread-8] Started
[setupThread] Finished
[Thread-9] Started
[Thread-2] 0 -> 1
[Thread-2] Finished
[Thread-6] 1 -> 2
[Thread-6] Finished
[Thread-4] 2 -> 3
[Thread-4] Finished
[Thread-5] 3 -> 4
[Thread-5] Finished
[Thread-1] 4 -> 5
[Thread-1] Finished
[Thread-0] 5 -> 6
[Thread-0] Finished
[main] Waiting for the value to reach 10
[Thread-7] 6 -> 7
[Thread-7] Finished
[Thread-8] 7 -> 8
[Thread-8] Finished
[Thread-3] 8 -> 9
[Thread-3] Finished
[Thread-9] 9 -> 10
[Thread-9] Finished
[main] Finished
```

Locking individual objects allows you for operating on more objects at a time.

https://onecompiler.com/jshell/3ytda2qwz